# indexator of binary search tree

Tags: c#

I created a binary search tree. I need to implement an indexator, which helps me to get element of tree, but it must be a part of sorted sequence. Of course, I could do something like

```
public T this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                var list = this.ToList();
                return list[i];
            }
        }
```

because I already implemented public `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`, which gets sorted sequence, but it is very slow to use, if I have a lot of calls like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    tree.Add(i);
    Console.Write(tree[i]);
}
```

I want to optimize this task. How?
Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BinaryTrees
{
    public class BinaryTree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
        where T : IComparable

    {
        private Node root;
        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public class Node
        {
            public Node left, right;
            public T value;
        }

        public BinaryTree()
        {
            root = new Node();
        }

        public T this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                var list = this.ToList(); 
                                          //How to 
                                          //make it fast??
                return list[i];
            }
        }

        public void Add(T key)
        {
            var current = root;

            while (true)
            {
                if (Count == 0)
                {
                    current.value = key;
                    Count++;
                    break;
                }

                if (key.CompareTo(current.value) <= 0)
                {
                    if (current.left == null)
                    {
                        current.left = new Node { value = key };
                        Count++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        current = current.left;
                }

                if (key.CompareTo(current.value) > 0)
                {
                    if (current.right == null)
                    {
                        current.right = new Node { value = key };
                        Count++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        current = current.right;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(T key)
        {
            var current = root;
            while (true)
            {
                if (Count == 0)
                    return false;

                if (current == null)
                    return false;

                var result = key.CompareTo(current.value);

                if (result == 0)
                    return true;

                if (result < 0)
                {
                    current = current.left;
                }
                else if (result > 0)
                {
                    current = current.right;
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var stack = new Stack<Node>();

            var current = root;

            var done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                if (current != null)
                {
                    stack.Push(current);
                    current = current.left;
                }

                else if (stack.Count != 0)
                {
                    current = stack.Pop();

                    yield return current.value;

                    current = current.right;
                }

                else done = true;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

I thaught, maybe I can make an array, which I can sort in indexator just if I added an element, but I realized that it as bad idea too.

Comment: Are you willing to trade memory for improving indexing performance ?

Comment: Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, Maybe, if I have no choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to avoid indexing as much as possible. If you already have enumerator, and need the index, keep it manually, and don't index. If you need the node after insertion, return it form the add method:

```
int index =0;
foreach (var item in tree)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"At {index} - {item}");
    index++;
}
```

If this is not possible, optimizing index access requires the use of extra memory to keep track of how many nodes there are on each branch of the tree and using this information to index. This has several side effects:

- It increases the size of a `Node` object by the amount of bytes of the `Count` field (for `int` - 4 bytes for example) which might not be trivial
- It adds complexity to keep this fields up to date on `Add` and `Remove`
- It limits the maximum number of elements the tree can hold to the size of the data type used for the count.

If you are ok with these tradeoffs you could do it like this: You keep in each node the count of elements in that subtree. If the index is bigger then the count in the left tree, the index is in the right subtree, if the index is lower, the index is in the left tree, if the index is equal to the count in the left subtree, that means the searched for index is the current element. If we go on the right tree, we need to adjust the index to be the index relative to the right subtree.

```
public class BinaryTree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
   where T : IComparable

{
    private Node root;
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public class Node
    {
        public int count;
        public Node left, right;
        public T value;
    }

    public BinaryTree()
    {
        root = new Node();
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            var current = this.root;
            while (true)
            {
                int beforeCount = current.left?.count ?? 0;
                if (beforeCount == i ) return current.value;

                if (beforeCount < i)
                {
                    i = i - beforeCount - 1;
                    current = current.right;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.left;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void Add(T key)
    {
        var current = root;
        if (Count == 0)
        {
            current.value = key;
            current.count = 1;
            Count++;
            return;
        }
        while (true)
        {
            current.count++;
            if (key.CompareTo(current.value) <= 0)
            {
                if (current.left == null)
                {
                    current.left = new Node { value = key, count = 1 };
                    Count++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.left;
                }
            }
            else if (key.CompareTo(current.value) > 0)
            {
                if (current.right == null)
                {
                    current.right = new Node { value = key, count = 1 };
                    Count++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.right;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @МихаилХамхоев There is an explanation of the code in the answer, is it not clear ? You use the number of items in each subtree to decide on what branch you have to go, and adjust the index relative to that